# Display TextBox with decimal value in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I use TextBox with decimal value in my view for post to my controller with decimal parameter like this:

```cs
    @Html.TextBox("PostDecimal", DecimalValue, new { type = "number", @min = 1, @max = 50, @step = 0.001 })
```

But the value is not showing in input view. Anyone know the correct line for this?

Comment: Where does `DecimalValue` come from? And what if you replace it with a number? `@Html.TextBox("PostDecimal", 8, new`

Comment: Tested this with `public decimal DecimalValue {get;set;} = 0.4m;` in model, no problems

Comment: @VDWWD that `DecimalValue` is from decimal variable, I just rewrote it, not copying from my code

Comment: As @RoarS. says, it all works fine. Are you sending the correct model?

Comment: Are you using some kind of slider in this TextBox?